# How can I submit a form automatically when grabbing a query string from the URL in REACT.js

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a form that I would like to submit automatically when a user lands on the page, IF the following string is in the URL hyperlink they receive:`?stxt=any+search+term`

Right now I am able to populate the state of query and the value of the input, but I am unable to trigger a form submit.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?stxt=") > -1) {
        var directories = window.location.href.split('/');
        this.queryUrl = directories[directories.length-1].replace('?stxt=', '').replace('%20', ' ');
}
```

```
if(this.queryUrl === undefined) {
    this.setState({
        query: ""
    })
} else {
    this.setState({
        query: queryUrl
    })
}
```

Here is the form:

```
<form id="form" onSubmit= { this.handleOnSubmit } className="src__input-container">
     <div className="src__total-search">
          <div className="search-container">
             <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
             <input
                className="src__search"
                type="text"
                value={query}
                name="search_filter"
                id="search-input"
                placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Search..."
                onChange ={ this.handleOnInputChange }
                onClick = {this.handleSearchClick}
                onKeyDown = {this.handleOnKeyDown}
                autoComplete="off"/>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div className="src__go-btn-container">
            <input className="go-btn" type="submit" value="GO" />
       </div>
</form>
```

Is there a built in function in React.js or a lifecycle that I'm supposed to be triggering the submit. I've tried in a `componentDidMount();` but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can submit form but selecting a dom of the form using `document.getElementById("myForm")` or by using React `ref` and then call submit method on it like this `document.getElementById("myForm").submit()`, the only tricky part is to when calling it. if you want to do it right after you setState with your `queryUrl` then setState accepts a callback as a second paramater that will be called after the state was set. so this will work:

```js
    this.setState({
        query: queryUrl
    }, () => {
       document.getElementById("myForm").submit()
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeny, but unfortunately that didn't work. It just reset my form. No console errors.

Comment: I think it would be best if you just edit your answer and include it there, it might be helpful to other people as well to answer this question.

Comment: so `document.getElementById("form").submit()` didn't work for you?

Comment: No. It loads the page and then reloads the page.

Comment: @NonnaVee why not doing like this https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-pond-wldcr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Nonna Vee the default action on submit of an HTML form (which includes reactJS form submit) is to reload the page see this link for docs https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyKlimenchenko, With your help I finally got it working!